# Servicestack Ormlite - weak / generic reference (like ReferencesAny in nhibernate)

Tags: weak-references, ormlite-servicestack

In nHibernate you can declare a column as `object` and map it as weak reference:

```
public virtual object TableRef{get;set;}

// then in the fluent mapping:
ReferencesAny(x => x.TableRef)
```

How would you acheive that kind of mapping in Servicestack ormlite

**Update**
I have a conditional reference need. I want to have a reference to 3 entities with one field. so when I query the database, I will get the correct reference.

```
public class UserEntity{

   public long Id {get;set;}
   public object MyPrimaryAnimal {get;set;}
}
```

`MyPrimaryAnimal` Maybe: `CatEntity`, `DogEntity` or `BirdEntity`.

This is the best use-case I could think of. weak reference. (I have ormlite license)

Thanks

Comment: OrmLtie and NHibernate are completely different ORMs, you're not going to NHibernate concepts in OrmLite, their approaches and design are radically different.

Comment: @mythz it does not mean that it is not possible

Comment: @SexyMF All Software is possible but this Nhibernate concept doesn’t exist in OrmLite so it’s not possible now and OrmLite doesn’t look to NHibernate for any of its features so it’s unlikely it will ever add it. If it was clear what use case the Author was trying to accomplish, it’d be easier to answer what the best way to do this with OrmLite would be.

Comment: @mythz I have updated my question. (Didnt know that you are the CTO  ) thanks

Answer (score 2):

Personally I dislike unknown/untyped properties so I'd never try to shove unknown types into a single untyped field. My first preference would be to use a single flat concrete structure, similar to how you would already design RDBMS tables with a single flat table of different columns capturing all the information you would want to capture, either on the entity table itself:

```
public class UserEntity
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
    //.. flattened properties of everything you want captured
}
```

Or if I'd need to capture the same info on multiple tables, a single class with all properties you'd want to capture, e.g:

```
public class UserEntity
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   //[Reference] // Optional: Save in external Animal table
   public Animal MyPrimaryAnimal {get;set;}
}

public class Animal
{
    public string Type { get; set; } // e.g. Cat, Dog, Bird
    //.. flattened properties of everything you want captured
}
```

Complex Type properties are automatically blobbed in OrmLite, or you can add the the `[Reference]` attribute to enlist [OrmLite's POCO References support](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#reference-support-poco-style) to have the data persisted in an external `Animal` table.

> You'll need to add the FK reference either on the `UserEntity` or `Animal` class for 1:1 mappings like this

#### Different Concrete Type Properties

My 2nd preference would to have different typed properties for each different property I'd want to store, e.g:

```
public class UserEntity
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public CatEntity CatEntity { get; set; }
   public DogEntity DogEntity { get; set; }
   public BirdEntity BirdEntity { get; set; }
}
```

Everything then works as normal, you'll always be dealing with concrete types when saving your `UserEntity` in OrmLite which will blob the complex type behind the scenes.

#### Saving unknown base Types in a Object Dictionary

If I absolutely needed to store different entities in a single field I'd store it into an Object Dictionary and provide a typed wrapper to persist/retrieve the base entity type, e.g:

```
public class UserEntity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [DataAnnotations.Ignore]
    public AnimalEntity MyPrimaryAnimal
    {
        get => AnimalEntity.FromObjectDictionary(AnimalRef);
        set => AnimalRef = value.ToObjectDictionary();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, object> AnimalRef { get; set; }
}
```

`AnimalEntity` would contain all base type properties and a factory function to return the concrete Type based on a `Type` identifier, e.g:

```
public class AnimalEntity
{
    public string Type => GetType().Name;

    public static AnimalEntity FromObjectDictionary(Dictionary<string, object> props)
    {
        if (props == null) return null;
        var type = props[nameof(Type)];
        switch (type) 
        {
            case nameof(DogEntity):
                return props.FromObjectDictionary<DogEntity>();
            case nameof(CatEntity):
                return props.FromObjectDictionary<CatEntity>();
            case nameof(BirdEntity):
                return props.FromObjectDictionary<BirdEntity>();
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException($"Unknown Animal '{type}'");
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can have as many sub types as you wish:

```
public class CatEntity : AnimalEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Cat { get; set; }
}

public class DogEntity : AnimalEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Dog { get; set; }
}

public class BirdEntity : AnimalEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Bird { get; set; }
}
```

That you can save and retrieve as Typed entities, e.g:

```
db.Insert(new UserEntity {Id = 1, MyPrimaryAnimal = new BirdEntity {Id = 1, Bird = "B"}});
db.Insert(new UserEntity {Id = 2, MyPrimaryAnimal = new CatEntity {Id = 1, Cat = "C"}});
db.Insert(new UserEntity {Id = 3, MyPrimaryAnimal = new DogEntity {Id = 1, Dog = "D"}});

var results = db.Select<UserEntity>();
var animals = results.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Map(x => x.MyPrimaryAnimal);

animals[0] //= BirdEntity 
animals[1] //= CatEntity 
animals[2] //= DogEntity
```

#### External References

If I just needed a single field to store a reference to any entity in a single field it's common to use a urn

```
public class UserEntity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string AnimalRef { get; set; }
}
```

Which you can use ServiceStack's `IdUtils.CreateUrn<T>` API or `ToUrn<T>` extension method:

```
db.Insert(new UserEntity {Id = 1, AnimalRef = 1.ToUrn<BirdEntity>() });
db.Insert(new UserEntity {Id = 2, AnimalRef = 2.ToUrn<CatEntity>() });
db.Insert(new UserEntity {Id = 3, AnimalRef = 3.ToUrn<DogEntity>() });
```

This will save the following string references:

```
urn:birdentity:1
urn:catentity:2
urn:dogentity:3
```

If you want to load the references you'll need a helper function to split the urn, match on the type and return the entity reference by Id.